# how to create a checkbox for each hash in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, ruby

I have a .JSON file that contains an array of hashes, each hash contains some info. regardless, i want to write a code that creates a checkbox for each hash, provided that the code has to be dynamic (if the number of hashes in the array changes, the code still works)

I'm using Ruby for the backend and HTML/JavaScript for the frontend

I was able to get a method that converts the .json file into "something useful I could use" :D

```
response = HTTParty.get("file.json")
i = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

and I learned how to create a checkbox in HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1">option 1< br>
```

but I know this does not create a checkbox for the item (hash in this case) inside the array and I want it to be repeated "x" number of times (provided that "x" is the number of hashes in the array)

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+dynamic+checkbox+json+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Try an [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combined with [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: And you can use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) on the front end to get the JSON file

Answer (score -1):

It will executes when the window finishes loading. It uses an asynchronous arrow function to fetch data from a remote server and display it on a web page. The function fetches data from a server at a specific URL using the fetch() method with a GET request and expects the response to be in JSON format. It then checks if the response is an array, and if it is, it creates an HTML element for each element in the response using a for loop and template literals. The HTML elements include a checkbox input and a label for each element in the response. Finally, it sets the innerHTML of an element with the ID "data" to the HTML created in the previous step, which displays the data on the web page. If there is an error while fetching data from the server or parsing the response, it logs an error message to the console.

```
window.onload = function() {
(async () => {
    try {
        let data = ``;
        let response = await fetch('https://reqbin.com/echo/get/json', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
        })
        response=  response.json();
        if (!Array.isArray(response)) throw Error(`Invalid response. Expecting Array found ${typeof response}`);
        for (const element of response) {
            data+= `
            <p>
                <input type="checkbox" value="${element}" title="${element}" id="${element}"/>
                <label for="${element}">${element}</label>
            </p>
            `
        }
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error", error.message)
    }
})()
};
```

Comment: Is this written by ChatGPT or do you just not realize the difference between JS and Rails?

Comment: Do chatgpt prepare code in this way? I have written all code myself for this particular problem. I dont know about rails but I am good in JS. The issue was in the JS part so I helped with the part i know. Is there any rails code involved in this ? or you just started giving negative comment with your own thoughs. Also please try using the chatgpt for the same problem and lets see if you get the same Corrected script I have given.

Comment: Javascript is totally irrelvant to the question.